# Json Volley Fragments from TabHost

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-volley

I'm downloading data from server and I want to set into ListView. It doesn't work. Below it's the method which provides get data from server.

```
 @Override
public void getVillages(String name, final TaskDoneListener<Village> listener) {
    String url = APIService.URL_BASE + "villages/search?s=" + name;
    final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Village village = new Village(
                        response.getLong("id"),
                        response.getString("name"),
                        response.getString("logo"),
                        response.getBoolean("isActive"),
                        response.getString("contact_person"),
                        response.getString("contact_email"),
                        response.getString("contact_person"),
                        response.getString("contact_phone"),
                        response.getString("contact_form_email"),
                        response.getString("latitude"),
                        response.getString("longitude"),
                        response.getString("region"),
                        outputFormatter.parseDateTime(response.getString("valid_from")),
                        outputFormatter.parseDateTime(response.getString("valid_to")));
                List<Village> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(village);
                Log.i("api", "delka " + list.size());
                listener.OnTaskDone(list);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;

            if (networkResponse != null) {
                int code = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                Log.i("getVillages", "ERROR response CODE: " + code);
            }
        }
    });


    apiService.addToRequestQueue(req, "LIST_VILLAGES");
```

My custom adapter

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Village> {
private Context mContext;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;
private int resource;

public SearchAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    mContext = context;
    this.resource = resource;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = getWorkingView(convertView);
    viewHolder = getViewHolder(view);
    final Village entry = getItem(position);
    Log.i("VillageAPIService", entry.getName());
    viewHolder.name.setText(entry.getName());

    return view;
}

private View getWorkingView(final View convertView) {
    View workingView = null;

    if (null == convertView) {
        final Context context = getContext();
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        workingView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    } else {
        workingView = convertView;
    }

    return workingView;
}

private ViewHolder getViewHolder(final View workingView) {
    final Object tag = workingView.getTag();
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (null == tag || !(tag instanceof ViewHolder)) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        workingView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) tag;
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

public void addAll(List<Village> villageList) {
    super.addAll(villageList);
}

private ViewHolder getViewHolder(final View view) {
    final Object tag = view.getTag();
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (null == tag || !(tag instanceof ViewHolder)) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) tag;
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

public void addAll(List<Village> villageList) {
    super.addAll(villageList);
}



static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}
```

}

This is the fragment which is started from TabHost and here I call the getVillages.

```
public class NewVillageSearchFragment extends Fragment {

private IVillageAPIService villageAPIService;
SearchAdapter mAdapter;
TextView tv;

public NewVillageSearchFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    villageAPIService = Bootstrapper.getVillageAPIService();


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_village_search, container, false);

    return v;

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final SearchAdapter adapter = new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_new_village);
    Log.i("Api", "onActivityCreated ");

    if(!(villageAPIService == null)) Log.i("Api", "villageApiService neni null ");
    String name = "Adamov";

    villageAPIService.getVillages(name, new TaskDoneListener<Village>() {
        @Override
        public void OnTaskDone(List<Village> list) {
            if(list.isEmpty()) Log.i("NewSearchFragment", "je prazdny");
            Log.i("NewSearchFragment", "after ||list: " + list.size());
            adapter.addAll(list);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });

}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I haven't seen the entire code but in your `onResponse` in the `JSONObjectRequest` you are creating a new ArrayList everytime and adding the new response to it. Hence the list will always contain 1 element only..

Comment: I've created before calling onResponse but OnTaskDone is never called. I don't know why.

Comment: is `OnResponse` called? Did you check the logcat for any exceptions? The only way that `OnTaskDone` wont be called when you get a response is if a `JSONException` occurs before while trying to create the village object

Answer (score 0):

I think You 're wrong How to use listener

You have to implements TaskDoneListener in NewVillageSearchFragment.

Exampe code below.

```
public class NewVillageSearchFragment extends Fragment implements TaskDoneListener {

    ....(omit code)

    @Override
    public void OnTaskDone(List<Village> list) {
        if(list.isEmpty()) Log.i("NewSearchFragment", "je prazdny");
        Log.i("NewSearchFragment", "after ||list: " + list.size());
        adapter.addAll(list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ...(omit code)

        villageAPIService.getVillages(name, this);
     }
```

Comment: Did you check out to call villageAPIService.getVillage?